# Command only logs messages deleted or edited in the channel set as a log

Tags: python, discord.py

The command is supposed to log any and every edited or deleted message from the server but only logs the ones from the channel set as the log channel. Where did I go wrong?

```py
try:
    with open('log_channels.json') as f:
        bot.ids = set(json.load(f))
    print("Loaded channels file")
except FileNotFoundError:
    bot.ids = set()
    print("No channels file found")

@bot.command()
async def channel(ctx, channel_id):
    try:
        channel_id = int(channel_id)
    except ValueError:
        await ctx.channel.send("Channel must be all digits")
        return

    if channel_id in bot.ids:
        await ctx.channel.send(f"Channel <#{channel_id}> is already set up.")
        return

    bot.ids.add(channel_id)
    with open('log_channels.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(list(bot.ids), f)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"Successfully set up <#{channel_id}>")


@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if message.channel.id in bot.ids and message.author != bot.user:
        deleted = Embed(
            description=f"Message deleted in {message.channel.mention}").set_author(name=message.author,
                                                                                    url=Embed.Empty,
                                                                                    icon_url=message.author.avatar_url)
        deleted.add_field(name="Message deleted", value=message.content)
        deleted.timestamp = message.created_at
        await message.channel.send(embed=deleted)

    # Pass processing on to the bot's command(s)
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning, you check if the message's channel is in one of the log channels.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if message.channel.id in bot.ids and message.author != bot.user:
        ...
```

You probably did not mean to add that check. Simply remove it, and then the event should execute for all channels:

```py
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if message.author != bot.user:
        ...
```

Note that the message delete event will not execute if it isn't cached, but you can increase the `max_messages` of the bot to have it recognize more messages ([here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=cache#discord.Client)).

Comment: after using your input it outputs the log however its not in the channel thats set to log with that command

Comment: Yeah, you're doing `await message.channel.send(embed=deleted)`. You're going to need to get the log channel. I think you have all the IDs as a list, so you have to find the right channel (I would recommend storing it as a dictionary instead, mapping the guild id to the channel id), then `get_channel` and send the message.